# Getting all entries from all locales

Tags: entries, localization

Can anyone confirm if I want to pull back a list of all entries regardless of locale I could do something like `craft.entries.locale(null)` to get 100% of entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience this has been problematic - instead have looped through locales to fetch entries then merged and sorted with supersort.

Eg:

```
{% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocales %}   

{% set pages = [] %}    

{% for locale in locales %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.locale(locale.id).localeEnabled(false).find() %} 
    {% set pages = pages|merge(entries) %}
{% endfor %}    

{% set pages = pages|supersort('rsortAs', "{ postDate|date('Ymd') }") %}
```

Then loop through pages as you would your entries. Am sure there is a more elegant way of doing this but this is what we had to do for our site.

Comment: Oh god this sounds down right dirty. I do hope there is a better way, but thank you for your answer. I will investigate when I get into this project, thanks!

Comment: Here is the supersort twig filter I presume Cole is referring to: https://topshelfcraft.com/lagniappe/supersort